# Mean Value Theorem for Convex derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

> Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ be differentiable. Assume that the set of
>   derivatives $$\{f'(x)\in L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m):x\in [a,b]\} \text{ is convex.}$$
>
> Prove that there exist a $θ$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(b)−f(a)=f'(θ)(b−a)$.

This is problem number $17$ from chapter $5$ of "[*Real mathematical analysis*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/144192941X)" by Charles Chapman Pugh [Springer (February 19, 2010)]. If $f$ is $C^1$, there is a straightforward proof. Could anyone help to prove or disprove this statement without $C^1$ condition?

Comment: what have you done for the problem ? what are your thoughts ?

Comment: Are you sure $x \in [a, b]$, because $f$ is defined in $R^n.$

Comment: @WillM.: In general, the notation $[x,y] $ means the convex hull of $\{x,y\}$.

Comment: There is another answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1676680/27978, but I can't follow it.

Comment: Just a guess here, but I would suspect that the author inadvertently omitted a $C^1$ hypothesis. I imagine that he intended Theorem 12 in Chapter 5 to be used to prove this and this requires $C^1$. Perhaps (more likely) he knows of some Darboux like theorem for higher dimensions.

Comment: This statement doesn't appear in Cartan's Calcul différentiel ...

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, since it assumes that $f$ is $C^1$.

Here are some hints if $f$ is $C^1$.

Let $R = \{ f'(x)(b-a) | x \in [a,b] \}$ and note that $R$ is convex
and compact (since $f'([a,b])$ is compact).

Note that $p \in R$ **iff** $\phi^T p \in \phi^T R$ for all linear functionals $\phi$.

You want to show that $f(b)-f(a) \in R$.

Note that the ordinary mean value theorem applies to
$\phi^T f$.

Comment: Can you explain it more? For example how should we use that $R$ is convex and closed?and also proof of the second statement is not seem easy!

Comment: I think I made an incorrect statement...

Comment: I will delete shortly.

Comment: The problem with the above is that $R$ is not obviously closed.

Comment: Pugh was one of my qualifying exam committee members :-). Long time ago :-(.